# Insert Comma Separated values through MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have one table (in phpmyadmin) with the following fields and structure:

```
Table 1
id  | sponsor
1   | -1 
2   | 1  
3   | 1  
4   | 2  
5   | 4  
6   | 4
```

Now i want to insert data from above table into new table as below:

```
Table 2
id  | children
1   | 2,3
2   | 4 
3   |   
4   | 5,6
5   |   
6   |
```

Actually this is Tree structure, which i have saved in mysql database. 
I have already written a script in php but as there are more then 100K rows in table 1 so its taking too much time. Please tell me an efficient sql query to do this task quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLE Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d76d3/10)**

```
SELECT 
t1.id,
(SELECT group_concat(id separator ', ')
  FROM table1 t2
   WHERE t2.sponsor = t1.id) AS children
FROM table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.id
```

Result:

```
| ID | CHILDREN |
-----------------
|  1 |     2, 3 |
|  2 |        4 |
|  3 |   (null) |
|  4 |     5, 6 |
|  5 |   (null) |
|  6 |   (null) |
```

Insert Statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT 
    t1.id,
    (SELECT group_concat(id separator ', ')
      FROM table1 t2
       WHERE t2.sponsor = t1.id) AS children
    FROM table1 t1
    GROUP BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [@Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13378771/297408) but uses a left join instead of a correlated subquery:

```sql
INSERT INTO Table2 (id, children)
SELECT
  sp.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ch.id) AS children
FROM Table1 sp
LEFT JOIN Table1 ch ON sp.id = ch.sponsor
GROUP BY t1.id
;
```

A demonstration of the SELECT statement's result can be found (and played with) [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d76d3/15) (the schema having been borrowed from Justin).

Answer (score 1):

One of your SELECT elements should be a `GROUP_CONCAT(...) as column`, which will concatenate those values separated with commas. If you want to filter by one of those values, you can use `GROUP BY -whatever- HAVING find_in_set( -number- , column )`

Comment: Can you please write query here ?

Answer (score 0):

See if the following helps

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT sponsor, GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: This is giving following output: -1 1,
1 2,
1 3 ,
2 4 ,
4 5 ,
4 6 ,